# How to make temp directory in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I need the CMake analog of mktemp command in linux. What macro provides this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct CMake analog of "mktemp".

From inside a CMake script or CMakeLists.txt file, your best bet is to use the

```
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "/path/to/dir/name")
```

command, and give it a name of a directory that you know you have write access to. Help for the file command is found here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html

You could also possibly simply use

```
$ENV{TMP}
```

if there is an environment variable that points you to a system-provided temp directory.

If you are invoking CMake directly, you could also use

```
cmake -E make_directory /path/to/dir/name
```

Finally, see also the execute_process command, which allows you to call arbitrary command line tools from within a cmake script or CMakeLists file and capture the output. That may prove useful if you have another tool that you can call that gives you mktemp functionality. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html

Comment: thanks for this. but how i can generate name so i will be sure that no dir with same name exists?

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for this too to evaluate expressions as suggested in the [CMake Wiki](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#Substitution_of_command_names). Wrote some macros and an example for generating temp file names and executing them:

```
#!/usr/bin/cmake -P

macro(temp_name fname)
  if(${ARGC} GREATER 1) # Have to escape ARGC to correctly compare
    set(_base ${ARGV1})
  else(${ARGC} GREATER 1)
    set(_base ".cmake-tmp")
  endif(${ARGC} GREATER 1)
  set(_counter 0)
  while(EXISTS "${_base}${_counter}")
    math(EXPR _counter "${_counter} + 1")
  endwhile(EXISTS "${_base}${_counter}")
  set(${fname} "${_base}${_counter}")
endmacro(temp_name)

# Evaluate expression
# Suggestion from the Wiki: http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax
# Unfortunately, no built-in stuff for this: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=4034
macro(eval expr)
  temp_name(_fname)
  file(WRITE ${_fname} "${expr}")
  include(${_fname})
  file(REMOVE ${_fname})
endmacro(eval)


# Examples

eval("message(\"Hai\")")

set(funcs a;b)
macro(test_a arg)
  message("A: ${arg}")
endmacro(test_a)
macro(test_b arg)
  message("B: ${arg}")
endmacro(test_b)

foreach(func ${funcs})
  set(func_name test_${func})
  eval("${func_name}(\"Test\")")
endforeach(func)
```

Output:

```
Hai
A: Test
B: Test
```

Note that in Linux you can set this script to executable and run it using `cmake -P`. Useful for testing stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following macro:

```
#!/usr/bin/cmake -P
include(CMakeParseArguments)

function(MKTEMP)
  set(options CREATE_FOLDER CREATE_FILE)
  set(oneValueArgs PREFIX PARENT OUTPUT_VARIABLE)
  cmake_parse_arguments(MKTEMP "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "" ${ARGN})

  if(NOT DEFINED MKTEMP_CREATE_FOLDER)
    set(MKTEMP_CREATE_FOLDER FALSE)
  endif()

  if(NOT DEFINED MKTEMP_CREATE_FILE)
    set(MKTEMP_CREATE_FILE FALSE)
  endif()

  if(MKTEMP_CREATE_FOLDER AND MKTEMP_CREATE_FILE)
    # Can not create folder and file with the same name
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Both flags CREATE_FOLDER and CREATE_FILE are set")
  endif()

  if(NOT DEFINED MKTEMP_PREFIX)
    set(MKTEMP_PREFIX "tmp")
  endif()

  if(NOT DEFINED MKTEMP_PARENT)
    set(MKTEMP_PARENT "$ENV{TMP}")
  endif()

  set(_COUNTER 0)
  while(EXISTS "${MKTEMP_PARENT}/${MKTEMP_PREFIX}${_COUNTER}")
    math(EXPR _COUNTER "${_COUNTER} + 1")
  endwhile()
  set(_NAME "${MKTEMP_PARENT}/${MKTEMP_PREFIX}${_COUNTER}")
  set(${MKTEMP_OUTPUT_VARIABLE} "${_NAME}" PARENT_SCOPE)

  if(MKTEMP_CREATE_FOLDER)
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${_NAME}")
  elseif(MKTEMP_CREATE_FILE)
    file(WRITE "${_NAME}" "")
  endif()
endfunction()
```

Usage:

```
# only generate name - with default prefix ("tmp")
MKTEMP(OUTPUT_VARIABLE TMPONLYNAME)
message("TMPONLYNAME is ${TMPONLYNAME}")

# only generate name - with custom prefix ("myapp")
MKTEMP(PREFIX "myapp" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TMPONLYNAME)
message("TMPONLYNAME is ${TMPONLYNAME}")

# only generate name - use current folder as temp
MKTEMP(PARENT "." OUTPUT_VARIABLE TMPONLYNAME)
message("TMPONLYNAME is ${TMPONLYNAME}")

# create file
MKTEMP(PREFIX "myapp" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TMPFILE CREATE_FILE)
message("TMPFILE is ${TMPFILE}")
# ... work with file ...
file(REMOVE "${TMPFILE}")

# create folder
MKTEMP(PREFIX "myapp" OUTPUT_VARIABLE TMPFOLDER CREATE_FOLDER)
message("TMPFOLDER is ${TMPFOLDER}")
# ... work with folder ...
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${TMPFOLDER}")
```

Example of output on my Windows environment ("myapp7" the same because of deletion):

```
TMPONLYNAME is C:\Users\msuslov\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1
TMPONLYNAME is C:\Users\msuslov\AppData\Local\Temp\myapp7
TMPONLYNAME is .\tmp0
TMPFILE is C:\Users\msuslov\AppData\Local\Temp\myapp7
TMPFOLDER is C:\Users\msuslov\AppData\Local\Temp\myapp7
```